# how to center cell-content vertically?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, multicolumn

I really like to center the content of the cells vertically, but I do not know how to do it. Is there maybe someone who can help me? Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\usepackage{multirow,array} 
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c|}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Spieler $2$} \\ \cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & $s_{21}$  & $s_{22}$ & $s_{23}$ \\ \cline{2-5}
\multirow{2}*{Spieler $1$} 
& $s_{11}$ & $(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{2})$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-5}
& $s_{12}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for:

[image]

The obtain above picture of table is obtained by your code, where I erase `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}` (whic add only space above cells content) and add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`. So, the complete code (with some changes in setting of math expressions), is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage{multirow,array}
    \usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Spieler 2} \\ \cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & s_{21}  & s_{22} & s_{23} \\ \cline{2-5}
\multirow{2}*{Spieler 1}
& s_{11} & \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right) & (x,y) & (x,y) \\ \cline{2-5}
& s_{12} & (x,y) & (x,y) & (x,y) \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}

    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you really much for your help!! : D

Comment: Can you express your thankfulness with up vote my answer and even accept it :-)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest to use a version like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    Spieler $1$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Spieler $2$}\\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
                & $s_{21}$  & $s_{22}$ & $s_{23}$ \\\cmidrule(r){1-1}
                \cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
    $s_{11}$ & $(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{2})$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\ 
    $s_{12}$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and your version! It looks way better than my version : ). Anyway I will have to do it like my version. I am so sorry. I hope you are not angry. I will try once again to center the things^^