# how to change font-size of a tikz tree

Tags: fontsize, tikz-trees

Is there a possibility to change the font size of the text right on the line of the following tree? I would like to reduce it, so that the tree does not appear such big. I hope someone may help me. Thank you!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow,array} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}, 
ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}
                ]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

\draw (n11) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n21);
\draw[dotted] (n11) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
\draw[dotted] (n34) -- node[above,sloped] {drehen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node[above,sloped] {passen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node[above,sloped] {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node[above,sloped] {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like a very inefficient way to make a tree, you're doing everything manually. Anyway, you can set a new style like `alongpath/.style={above, sloped, font=\tiny}` or `\scriptsize`, then replace all your `\node[above, sloped] ...` with `\node[alongpath] ...`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I do not have much experiences with latex and that is why everything is new for me. What I can do other? : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make font size of texz in nodes smaller is quit simple. Two possible solution cross my mind:

- define node style, something like `edgenode/.style = {above,sloped,font=\small}` and than named nodes accordingly, for example `node[edgenode] {....}`
- collect those nodes in scope, in it define above for every node inside scope.

Complete code for second option is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}
                ]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,
                                     font=\footnotesize% <-- desired size
                                     }]
\draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
\draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
\draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you another question? Do you know what I can do in that case?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291644/how-to-center-cell-content-vertically

Comment: You can ask me, of course, unfortunately, I do not understand you. Which case? In given link is some table. Regarding your decision tree, I would look `trees` library, if it is more convenient to you (with it you don't care about absolute coordinates). Many people here prefer to use `forest` package (I still not learn it .-( ...). Be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description : ). Well beside these trees here I do also need some payoff matrix. But the content of the cells in the matrix mentioned is not vertically centered and it disturbs me but I do not know how to fix it. I hope you see what I mean. I know that the matrix does not look very fine, but there is no other possibility I found. Thank you!